# jquery empty and remove is not actually clearing the content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have to delete the form completely with its inner childrens and show some new div instead of it. As :

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  (function($) {

    try {
      $("#form1").empty();
      $("#form1").remove();
      $("body").append("<div><h1>New Heading</h1> ...some info </div>");
      $(document).attr("title", "Partial Data is Seen");
    } catch (e) {}
  })(jQuery);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="./userdata" id="form1">
    <div>
      <h1>User Info ....</h1>
      <user Data>
        . .
      </user Data>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

I want to remove the **Form1** completely with its children nodes and add a div with other data.

In web browser the user is seeing the new Title with new data, but in **View Page Source** its not actually removing, user can easily see all form data.
Why it is not removing ?

***What will be index by the Google and other Search engine*** ?

**Form1** Data  Or the **NewDiv** Data ?

Comment: You are probably looking at the source code send by the http(s) request wich will not change. If you want to prevent the user from seeing that you need to avoid it being send to the client on the server side.

Comment: What will Google Index ? Form1 Data or  My NewDiv Data ?

Comment: it will index everything it can see. it will also execute some JS, but it will always also see the source code itself.

Comment: will it execute my script (in header ) that replace the title, h1 tag and content ?
 and index the NewDiv Content ?